# Hide user login in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

I added a user account to my Windows XP box. This user is only accessing the PC remotely.

How can I remove the user from the login welcome screen? In fact, how can I eliminate the welcome screen altogether and just log into the box automatically from the main user account?

Answer (score 10):

To log in automatically you need to use Microsoft's [TweakUI Power Toy](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx)

1. Expand the Logon section
2. Select the Autologon section
3. Fill out the options

[image: TweakUI Autologon]

Answer (score 4):

Edit this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList
```

Add a new DWORD with a value of the exact username.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the Other user from the loginscreen.

You can go to the security policy

Start -> Run -> secpol.msc

Under Local Principles, Under ~"User Rights" (I don't know the english translation for this)
And then modify "Local Login" to Exclude this Remote Accessor.

That should do it.

---

To Autologin

Start -> run -> control userpasswords2 uncheck the box for requiring to give username and password upon login. Press Apply.

You will now be asked what Username and password you want to autologin.